# Azure Devops - Schedule agent update

Tags: azure-devops

We are running UI tests using Azure Interactive agent but sometime agent update's affects our test run. Can we schedule the agent update to happen on specific time.

Thought scheduling Maintenance for agents would solve this but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, **we do not have this kind of build-in feature to schedule agent update.**

If you do not want agent to update. You could try to set `agent.disableupdate=true` and check if this do the trick.

But if the server sends the update request and awaits the agent to update before considering the agent available.

This is an expected behavior, the agent only updates itself when it must. When you use a feature on **the service that requires a new agent**.

You could also take a look at this similar question here-- [Prevent agents automatically updating](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2455)